# Databricks Docker Container in Azure

Tags: docker, azure-databricks

I am unable to find enable custom container options in my databricks workspace admin setting.

Screenshot of Databricks workspace setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you can only do this via API/CLI/Terraform. Here is an example of the API code.

```
curl --request PATCH "https://${DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/workspace-conf" \
 --header "Authorization: Bearer ${DATABRICKS_TOKEN}" \
 --data '{ "enableDcs": "true" }'
```

More info can be found at
https://docs.databricks.com/en/clusters/custom-containers.html#enable